# Inserting multiple rows with loop

Tags: php, mysql, insert, mysql-error-1064

Code:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $arr['var']; $i++) {

  if($i == $arr['var']):

    $insert .= '('.$n_id.', 12)';

  else:

    $insert .= '('.$n_id.', 12),';

  endif;

}

$uz = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cars`
                   (n_id, auto_id)
                   VALUES
                   '$insert'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Why it gives me a SQL syntax error? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is insert initialized to before you enter this loop? You probably want to make sure it's set to the empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing string concatentation in the INSERT statement:

```
$uz = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cars`
                     (n_id, auto_id)
                   VALUES "
                    . $insert .") or die(mysql_error());
```

That's assuming you aren't also having an issue with the trailing comma for tuple support.

Comment: @MrXexxed: My choice, cuz I'm not 100% on my PHP

Comment: -1: No string concatenation is required (and in fact your quotes are clearly broken); the real issue was the use of `'` characters around the data list.

Comment: @OMGPonies: `") or die(mysql_error());` is broken quotes not only to me, but also to Stack Overflow's syntax highlighting algorithm.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: It's a Community Wiki answer - you can edit it, no?

Comment: @OMGPonies: Yes, I probably could. Given that the OP accepted it a year ago, though, I thought it would be more responsible to _draw attention_ first to the fact that this is broken and does not do anything to answer the question, rather than silently editing.

Answer (score 0):

- Your query, unexpanded, is this:

  ```
  INSERT INTO `cars` (n_id, auto_id) VALUES '$insert'
  ```

  Then, with `$insert` expanded, it probably looks something like this:

  ```
  INSERT INTO `cars` (n_id, auto_id) VALUES '(1,12),(2,12),(3,12)';
  ```
- Those single quotes (`'`) around the data list should not be there, as single quotes delimit strings.
- Instead, you want:

  ```
  INSERT INTO `cars` (n_id, auto_id) VALUES (1,12),(2,12),(3,12);
  ```

  Re-collapsing that into your PHP, you end up with:

  ```
  INSERT INTO `cars` (n_id, auto_id) VALUES $insert
  ```

---

**tl;dr:** remove the `'`s.

Answer (score -1):

Using backticks (around cars) is incorrect when mixed with single quotes (around $insert), to the best of my knowledge, in mySQL. Pick one or the other - single quotes are probably recommended for standardization.

Comment: -1: Nonsense. Backticks delimit fieldnames, whereas single quotes delimit strings.

Answer (score -1):

On [General SQL Management](http://forums.devarticles.com/general-sql-development-47/insert-into-single-row-vs-multiple-rows-7726.html) it gives this example for an insert into:

```
INSERT INTO [table]
( [field1], [field2], [field3] ) VALUES
( '[value1.1]', '[value1.2]', '[value1.3]' ),
( '[value2.1]', '[value2.2]', '[value2.3]' ),
( '[value3.1]', '[value3.2]', '[value3.3]' ),
etc.
```

You might have some syntax problems. I recommend printing out

```
"INSERT INTO `cars`
       (n_id, auto_id)
       VALUES
       '$insert'"
```

to see what you are sending.